# Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa20: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04

I have:

```
mona@pascal:~$ cat /etc/default/sysstat
#
# Default settings for /etc/init.d/sysstat, /etc/cron.d/sysstat
# and /etc/cron.daily/sysstat files
#

# Should sadc collect system activity informations? Valid values
# are "true" and "false". Please do not put other values, they
# will be overwritten by debconf!
ENABLED="true"
```

and then:

```
mona@pascal:~$ sudo sar -d
Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa20: No such file or directory
Please check if data collecting is enabled in /etc/default/sysstat
```

Can you please suggest a fix?

```
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo service sysstat start` afterwards?

Answer (score 48):

Open `/etc/default/sysstat` using your favorite file editor and change `ENABLED="false"` to `ENABLED="true"`

```
vi /etc/default/sysstat
----
# Should sadc collect system activity informations? Valid values
# are "true" and "false". Please do not put other values, they
# will be overwritten by debconf!
ENABLED="true"
----
```

Restart sysstat: `sudo service sysstat restart`

and now here you are!

Comment: o.m.g....... why would it not be enabled by default? Now that I need it that history, I find that it hasn't been collecting it for me. Past CPU and memory usage has been lost to the wind. Argh.

Comment: Unbelievable  that this is not enabled by default.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

For fresh installations (2022+): if you use **systemd**, do **NOT** edit `/etc/default/sysstat`, it won't work.

You must use dpkg:

```
dpkg-reconfigure sysstat
```

and select «Yes».

As the cron will check for **systemd**, if it exists it will silently fail. Using `dpkg-reconfigure` will enable systemd tasks:

- sysstat-collect
- sysstat-summary

that would run as expected every 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

This enabled and started it:

```
sudo sed -i "s|ENABLED="false"|ENABLED="true"|g" /etc/default/sysstat
sudo systemctl enable sysstat && sudo systemctl start sysstat
```

Had to wait like 15 min. to see newly recorded values in `sar` command output.